# How to determine the value type of proto3's oneof field?

Tags: grpc, grpc-python, proto3

```
syntax = "proto3";

package gRPC_Forecaster;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

service Forecaster {
    rpc Forecast (ProductToForecast) returns (ForecastData) {}
}

message ProductToForecast {
    int32 productID = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp startDate = 2;
    int32 forecastDurationInWeeks = 3;
    Model model = 4;
}

message ForecastData {
    repeated int32 data = 1;
    repeated int32 date = 2;
}

message Model {
    oneof model_oneof {
        ARIMA arima = 1;
        SARIMA sarima = 2;
    }
}

message ARIMA{
    int32 p = 1;
    int32 d = 2;
    int32 q = 3;
}

message SARIMA{
    int32 p = 1;
    int32 d = 2;
    int32 q = 3;
    int32 p2 = 4;
    int32 d2 = 5;
    int32 q2 = 6;

}
```

Above is my proto3 code for my gRPC setup, where I have a python sever and a PHP client.
On the PHP client i set the model object as ARIMA.
How do I check on my python server that the type of the request.model is of type ARIMA?
Also, I want the PHP client to be able to set the model to either ARIMA or SARIMA, is the way I am approaching this correct?

Comment: seems what you actually want to know is the usage of protocol buffer's `oneof` field, especially in Python and PHP programming language?

Comment: Once I send the request to the Python server in the python server I would like to do if request.model is ARIMA?? how could I approach this on python?

Comment: Hi @Lloen, I'd suggest retitle this question to  "How to determine the value type of proto3's oneof field?", as it is more concrete and may help future googlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at potocol buffers' reference for generated code:

- [Python](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#oneof)
- [PHP](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/php-generated#oneof)

Answer (score 0):

For now I found a solution with the [hasattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) function of Python.
So when I received a request from the PHP application I can do `hasattr(request.model, "arima")` and works. I am not certain this is the way to go.